# django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL: role "user" does not exist

Tags: django, database, postgresql, authentication, orm

I am trying to authenticate users with django and postgresql. My project is dockerized. When I run `docker-compose up --build` I get an error saying:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  role "django2" does not exist

I know error says role django2 doesn't exists but it does. If I run `CREATE ROLE django2;` I get an error saying `ERROR:  role "django2" already exists`.

**My DATABASE section of settings.py:**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'zane_db',
        'USER': 'django2',
        'PASSWORD': 'django2',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432
    }
}
```

**My registration view:**

```
letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",]
characters = letters + numbers
length = 5
token = "".join(random.sample(characters, length))

def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        context = {'has_error': False, 'data': request.POST}
        global password
        global password2
        global email
        global username
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        password2 = request.POST.get('password2')

        body = render_to_string('authentication/email/email_body.html', {
            'username': username,
            'token': token,
        })
        send_mail(
            "Email Confirmation",
            body,
            'tadejtilinger@gmail.com',
            [email]
        )
        return redirect('email-confirmation')
    return render(request, 'authentication/signup.html')


def email_confirmation(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        context = {'has_error': False, 'data': request.POST}

        code = request.POST.get('code')
        
        if code == token:
            if len(password) < 8:
                ############custom message
                context['has_error'] = True

            if password != password2:
                ############custom message
                context['has_error'] = True

            if not validate_email(email):
                ############custom message
                context['has_error'] = True

            if not username:
                ############custom message
                context['has_error'] = True

            if models.CustomUser.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                ############custom message
                context['has_error'] = True

                return render(request, 'authentication/signup.html', context, status=409)

            if models.CustomUser.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                ############custom message
                context['has_error'] = True

                return render(request, 'authentication/signup.html', context, status=409)

            if context['has_error']:
                return render(request, 'authentication/signup.html', context)

            user = models.CustomUser.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()

            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            login(request)

    return render(request, 'authentication/email/email_confirmation.html')
```

**My docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    tty: true
    build: .
    command: python3 /docekr/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/docekr
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:11
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

**My Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.9

ENV PYTHONUBBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

WORKDIR /zane

COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /zane/
RUN pip3 install pipenv && pipenv install --system

COPY . /zane/
```

Comment: can you share your Docker file or docker-compose.yml file

Comment: @P Studio Added the answer, please check if it works

Comment: 'If I run CREATE ROLE django2; I get an error saying ERROR:  role "django2" already exists.'  How did you connect in order to run that?  It sounds like you have multiple databases on your system, and are not consistently using the correct one.

Comment: @jjanes psql zane_db django2;

Answer (score 0):

you need to set `POSTGRES_USER` and `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` for your database. Change your docker-compose entry to this.

```
    db:
      image: postgres:11
      volumes:
        - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
      environment:
        POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
        POSTGRES_USER: django2
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: django2
      ports:
        - "5432:5432"
```

Comment: Nah it still results in same error:(
But if I change to this:
```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432
    }
}
```
It works fine.
Could you still try to figure out why is that?